# NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/UnmarshalException - Spring Security oauth2

Tags: spring, maven, oauth, jwt

Currently I'm working on securing a REST SpringBoot service. I've decided to use oauth2 with JWT. But I'm facing that strange error on application startup. I believe there must be some mistake on spring-security-core and spring-security-jwt versions. Here is stack:

```
    Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
    2017-11-17 11:47:34.428 ERROR 9604 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/UnmarshalException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at 
org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:527) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) [na:na]
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/UnmarshalException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        ... 26 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/UnmarshalException
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.DefaultOAuth2ExceptionRenderer.geDefaultMessageConverters(DefaultOAuth2ExceptionRenderer.java:117) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
...
        at 
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        ... 27 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:563) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496) ~[na:na]
        ... 51 common frames omitted
```

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

...

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Dependency for embed mongo testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    **<!-- Dependency for web security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>**
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
```

Is there anything that I've missed on that Configuration?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to include Jaxb Api, so in your `pom.xml` you should add its dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Alessandro. But now I've got Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory

Comment: That's in 
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency> see [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl/2.3.0)

Comment: This save my year! Thanks @Alessandro

Answer (score 2):

I've realize that changing my jdk from jdk-9.0.1 to jdk1.8.0_151, it works! But I did not understand why jdk-9 does not include jaxb support?!

Comment: Oh, Java 9 implements JPMS (Java Platform Module System) so you have to add jaxb module see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-F640FA9D-FB66-4D85-AD2B-D931174C09A3)